# Java EE using MongoDB without JPA or EJB?

Tags: mongodb, session, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

Could someone give me an explanation of if what I'm doing makes sense?

I am currently developing a Java EE application using MVC architecture, and MongoDB as my database.  What I have is several entities written as Java objects with custom mapping methods to persist to and from my MongoDB, as well as a separate controller class to perform Database queries and operations.  I am able to store these entities in my session with no problem, but I haven't tested this on a larger scale. I've tried annotating my objects as beans, however I received errors.

My typical method of transmitting data is to query my MongoDB, receive the information, map it to a java object, and store it in a session to be accessed by the front end.  Is this the proper way to go about this?

Do my entities need to be EJBs? What do I have to gain from making them EJBs? I'm sorry if this question is presented poorly and seems unintelligent.  I just want to have a better understanding of the technology I am trying to utilize before further developing.  Most of the reading I have done on such topics has been to no avail.  If anyone has some clear reading or an explanation that should help me understand what I am asking, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume by "EJBs", you are referring to "Entity Beans"? In EJB 3, entity beans are "replaced" by JPA. Think of JPA as a "specification" for ORM frameworks. JPA/ORM are frameworks for mapping Java objects to and from relational databases. You are using MongoDB, which is not a relational database, and hence not that suitable for JPA. So I would say no, there is no need for you to consider JPA. Instead you should consider other frameworks, like Spring Data, which can simplify the task you are doing.

Comment: I had a feeling that was true.  Everything I read about EJB and JPA came back to RDBMS, which wasn't relevant to me. I guess I was just worried that my objects needed "EJB Qualities" to be stored and operate properly in the session attribute. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

in my opinion you can use EJB3 with mongodb without JPA and entity manager, but you will have Stateless/Singleton/Startup/MDB beans with 0 configuration and with perfect managable backend.